# How can i show my (childData) array data in datatables form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, javabeans, suitecrm

How can show my data in table format

```
$ParentBean = BeanFactory::newBean('Users');

        $ParentBean = $ParentBean->retrieve_by_string_fields(
            array(
                'user_name' =>  $values =  $_POST['name'],
            )
        );
        if ($ParentBean->load_relationship('tc_users')) {
            $childData = $ParentBean->tc_users->getBeans();
        }
```

Right now i am using this to show my array

```
echo '<pre>';
        print_r($_POST);

        foreach ($childData as $key => $value) {
            echo $value->name;
            print_r($value);
            echo '<br>';
        }
```

RESULT:

```
Array
(
    [name] => admin
)
saSasLead Object
(
    [field_name_map] => Array
        (
            [id] => Array
                (
                    [name] => id
                    [vname] => LBL_ID
                    [type] => id
                    [required] => 1
                    [reportable] => 1
                    [comment] => Unique identifier
                    [inline_edit] => 
                )

            [name] => Array
                (
                    [name] => name
                    [rname] => name
                    [vname] => LBL_NAME
                    [type] => name
                    [link] => 1
                    [fields] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => first_name
                            [1] => last_name
                        )

                    [sort_on] => last_name
                    [source] => non-db
                    [group] => last_name
                    [len] => 255
                    [db_concat_fields] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => first_name
                            [1] => last_name
                        )

                    [importable] => false
                )

            [date_entered] => Array
                (
                    [name] => date_entered
                    [vname] => LBL_DATE_ENTERED
                    [type] => datetime
                    [group] => created_by_name
                    [comment] => Date record created
                    [enable_range_search] => 1
                    [options] => date_range_search_dom
                    [inline_edit] => 
                )
```

Comment: Write the code - nice way

Answer (score 1):

You can get it through:

```
$data= $accountBean->get_linked_beans(
                'contacts',
                'Contacts',
                array(),
                0,
                10,
                0,
                "contacts.primary_address_country = 'USA'");
```